# Adding additional variables to javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script that adds a class to an element on page scroll down. How might I add additional variables so I can add the class to individual elements as they come into view?

Here's the original:

```
// Returns true if the specified element has been scrolled into the viewport.
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
var $elem = $(elem);

// Get the scroll position of the page.
var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

// Get the position of the element on the page.
var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
var $elem = $('.flip-card');

// If the animation has already been started
if ($elem.hasClass('start')) return;

if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
    // Start the animation
    $elem.addClass('start');
}
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
checkAnimation();
});
```

And here's my updated script - that doesn't work:

```
// Returns true if the specified element has been scrolled into the viewport.
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
var $elem = $(elem);
var $elem2 = $(elem2);

// Get the scroll position of the page.
var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

// Get the position of the element on the page.
var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
var elem2Top = Math.round( $elem2.offset().top );
var elem2Bottom = elemTop + $elem2.height();

return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
return ((elem2Top < viewportBottom) && (elem2Bottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
var $elem = $('.flip-card');
var $elem2 = $('.flip-card-1');

// If the animation has already been started
if ($elem.hasClass('start')) return;

if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
    // Start the animation
    $elem.addClass('start');
}

if ($elem2.hasClass('start')) return;

if (isElementInViewport($elem2)) {
    // Start the animation
    $elem2.addClass('start');
}
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
checkAnimation();
});
```

I suppose I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: And where's the `elem2` variable coming from?

Comment: Did you forgot to give elem2 as argument at isElementInViewport ? :)

Comment: Oleg - I see what you mean. Would it be better to duplicate the entire function?

Comment: Freuh - no, it's there :)

Answer (score 0):

You just got to change youre checkAnimation function to this:

```
function checkAnimation() {
  var $elements = [$('.flip-card'), $('.flip-card-1')];

  $elements.forEach(function(element) {
    // If the animation has already been started
    if (element.hasClass('start')) return;

    if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
      // Start the animation
      element.addClass('start');
    }
  }
}
```

Just put all the elements that you want to check in an array. Then you can check for all the elements in that array.This way you don't need the second element in both methods.